# Does sidekiq failed count ever decrease?

Tags: delayed-job, sidekiq

I've recently transitioned from Delayed Job to Sidekiq. I've noticed that when a job fails, the Failed count increments and the job is placed in the Retries tab. Subsequent retries increment the Failed counter, but I've never noticed it decrement. Is this the proper behavior? If so, is it suggested that the counter be reset every once in a while?

[image: sidekiq dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the proper behavior. It never decreases, but you clean the queue: `Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.del('stat:failed') }`

Mike Perham explain it very well: http://librelist.com/browser//sidekiq/2014/4/14/does-sidekiq-failed-count-ever-decrease/#926522aa9cdaff47f035d3a313b16a59

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to post his answer to my dupe question there.